# Command to save and restore partitioning under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, partitioning, gpt

I know we can use `sfdisk` to save and restore partition tables.

Save:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > part_table
```

Restore:

```
sfdisk /dev/sda < part_table
```

But is there other command line tools to save and restore *partitioning*, works for disks big or small, MBR or gpt? By  "*partitioning*" I mean, not only to save and restore disk Ids (7, 82, 83, etc), but also partition types (like ntfs, ext4, btrfs, swap, etc), and even labels.

The `parted` can at least save partition types like this:

```
parted -ms /dev/sda print > sda.parted
```

But can it generate something that it can understand itself in order to restore the preserved partitioning? If not, any command line tools can please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a clear distinction in the data structures between the *partition table* and the *contents of partitions:*

- The partition table includes start and end points, type codes, and often some additional metadata about the partitions.
- Partitions' contents are generally filesystems, but they can be LVMs, swap partitions, boot loader code, etc.

From a software point of view, it's logical to separate the two, although there can be some bleed-through -- for instance, `parted` probes partitions' contents enough to determine the filesystem type. Many partitioning tools (particularly GUI tools) combine filesystem-manipulation features with partition-manipulation features. This can help with operations like resizing partitions, and also makes it easier for less-experienced users to destroy their data (er, "partition their disks" ;-) ) The underlying data structures are *entirely* separate, though -- filesystems are contained entirely *within* partitions. Type codes are mere "hints," which can often get out of sync with reality and therefore be misleading.

The question I have upon reading yours is: What do you *really* want to do? That is, what is your end goal? For instance, do you want to create a complete backup that you can restore? If so, something like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) might suit your needs. If you simply want a backup of the partition table itself in case of an accident with `dd` or the like, you don't need filesystem information, and the `sfdisk` command you specified (for MBR) or a backup created with `gdisk`'s `b` option (or `sgdisk -b`) (for GPT) will work. If you want a printed record for reference or manual replication or recovery, printing the output of `parted /dev/sda print` (or something similar) should do pretty well.